# Change splash screen for Catel+Orchestra application

Tags: customization, splash-screen, catel

Im trying to modify the default splash screen for my orchestra app. found the SplashScreen.png included by default on the resources/images folder and overwrote it with my own (same width and height). The splash screen did not change.

I went and looked at the code of Orchestra and found the SplashScreen view. And saw that you have a placeholder for the companylogo.

```
        <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding CompanyLogoForSplashScreenUri}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="0.7"
           Visibility="{Binding CompanyLogoForSplashScreenUri, Converter={catel:ReferenceToCollapsingVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

On the view model I found out the constructor calls on the IAboutInforService

```
public SplashScreenViewModel(IAboutInfoService aboutInfoService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => aboutInfoService);
        var aboutInfo = aboutInfoService.GetAboutInfo();
        CompanyLogoForSplashScreenUri = aboutInfo.CompanyLogoForSplashScreenUri;
    }
```

But the CompanyLogoForSplashScreenUri property in the AboutInfo object returned from the GetAboutInfo is always null. The constructor never adds the uri reference to it.

```
public AboutInfo GetAboutInfo()
    {
        var aboutInfo = new AboutInfo(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/CompanyLogo.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        return aboutInfo;
    }

public AboutInfo(Uri companyLogoUri = null, string logoImageSource = null, string url = null, Assembly assembly = null, Uri companyLogoForSplashScreenUri = null)
```

So what can I do to add a companylogo to the splashscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 *CompanyLogoUri* in the constructor. As you can see by the variable names, both have their own purpose:

1. companyLogoUri
2. companyLogoForSplashScreenUri

I think you want to set the 2nd ;-)